# Validare mongoose duplicates made of multiple fields

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I am using Nest.JS and i have an article schema

```
export class Article {
  @Prop()
  code: string;

  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  thumbnail: string;

  @Prop()
  document: string;

  @Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' })
  projectId;
}
```

I am using `insertMany` from mongoose to add new articles and ideally i'd like the function to skip creating articles which have the same `code` & `projectId`. I should insert the same `code` with different `projectId` but not both the same.

Is this possible to do without reading the entire article list in order to filter the new array.

Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Comment: How will you choose different `projectId` if they have same `code` and `projectId`?

Comment: this collection keeps articles for different projects and codes shouldn't be unique field cause you can have same code for different projects but not same code twice per project